# Objective-C: releasing the object from itself

Tags: objective-c

I've stumbled upon an interesting situation when object could release itself and was wondering what is considered safe and right in this situation.

Imagine we have a class Foo:

```
@implementation Foo
+ (Foo *) foo {
    return [[[Foo alloc] init] autorelease];
}

- (void)resign {
    [FooHolder holder].foo = nil;

    // here's where the things happen
}
@end
```

Another class is FooHolder (singleton with one property):

```
@interface FooHolder : NSObject {
    Foo *foo;
}

@property (retain) Foo *foo;

+ (FooHolder *)holder;

@end
```

And somewhere in the code we do this (calling first `stepOne` and then `stepTwo`; autorelease pools are drained after `stepOne` finishes):

```
- (void)stepOne {
    Foo *foo = [Foo foo];

    [FooHolder holder].foo = foo;
}

- (void)stepTwo {
    [[FooHolder holder].foo resign]
}
```

If I'm trying to access `self` in `resign` method, after the assignment, with NSZombieEnabled, I'm getting a warning that `self` is already deallocated. This gives me short WTF moment, but alright, I can live without accessing `self` at this part. What bothers me more, if object is already deallocated, who can guarantee that stack is not damaged, and we are proceeding normally with our local and instance variables? In general, is it a bad practice to allow `self` to be deallocated while in the method?

Comment: That particular use of the dot looks ugly;  i'd recommend just using regular method call syntax for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In general, is it a bad practice to allow self to be deallocated while in the method?

Yes because from the point that self is deallocated all of your ivars could also be deallocated.

I won't pretend to understand your design or your reasons for doing it but why do you not rearrange your resign method:

```
- (void)resign {
    // here's where the things should happen
    [FooHolder holder].foo = nil;
}
```

You should always release owned objects after there is any chance you will use them in the same way that you call `[super dealloc];` at the *end* of `-(void)dealloc`

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that you have a faulty design.  In the instance method `-resign` you are effectively releasing a particular instance of foo held by the singleton.  Why would any **arbitrary** instance of foo do that?  Referencing what is effectively a global variable in the instance method makes the coupling too tight.

Whatever invokes `-resign` should be the thing that tells `[FooHolder holder]` that it has resigned the `foo` or will resign the foo.  Alternatively, have a weak reference to a `FooHolder` in the `foo` and have the `foo` send it a message like `-willResign:(Foo*)`  This effectively makes it a delegate of the `foo`.  In `-willResign:` the `FooHolder` can check if it is the right `foo` and then retain and autorelease it before setting it to nil.